# Return JSON Object by Value of a Key

Tags: javascript, json

I have a huge nested JSON object, and need to find a specific one by a certain value of a certain key.

For example:

```
[ { 
      id: 't53',
      action: 'Boot',
      time: 2019-04-21T17:58:34.579Z
  },
  { 
      id: 't54',
      action: 'Reset',
      time: 2019-04-24T17:57:33.549Z
  } ]
```

So, if need to find the object where *action* is *Boot*, and the result must be:

```
{ 
    id: 't54',
    action: 'Boot',
    time: 2019-04-24T17:57:33.549Z
}
```

Comment: Just use `filter()` or `find()` https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: In your example, both elements have action = Boot, can you clarify why do you expect to get only the second one?

Comment: Bady copy/paste from my part. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array.find` method to get the first item that matches the condition.

```
const item = objs.find(obj => obj.action === 'Boot');
```

If you want to find the first element from last, you could create a shallow copy of the array and reverse it.

```
const item = objs.slice().reverse().find(obj => obj.action === 'Boot');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [{ 
      id: 't53',
      action: 'Boot',
      time: '2019-04-21T17:58:34.579Z'
  },
  { 
      id: 't54',
      action: 'Boot',
      time: '2019-04-24T17:57:33.549Z'
  }];


var result = data.filter(a => a.action === 'Boot');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You loop over the array and check each item action key is you want or not.

Comment: with built-in functions like filter and map, you don't need to use for loop.